# How do I know dead links in Google ad-words?

Tags: web-development, google-ads

I am spending a lot of money on Google ad-words in my website. Sometimes customers get dead links from ad-words and unable to get to intended page.

I know this is an issue from my part. I need to know which are those dead links that ad-words lists?

Is there any way to find this?

Answer (score 3):

Check your webserver logs and look from 404 responses refereed by google and identify em by GCLID.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365888/how-to-decode-google-gclids